# How to stop incrementing a variable when drop in same dropspot

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 7 dropspots and 7 draggable elements. I can use same element for all 7 dropspots or i can use all draggable elements on same dropspot. I have a variable contor wich increment at drop, but, if i drag all elements on same dropspot this variable reach 7 and something happens. What i need is to increment that variable only once per dropspot even if i drop and change src 7 times in same dropspot. My code looks like :

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GLRa9/2/)

```
drop: function( event, ui )
{
    dropTarget = event.target.id;
    indexDrops = dropTarget.charAt(dropTarget.length-1);
    $("#dropspot" + indexDrops).css("opacity", 0);
    $("#dropspot" + indexDrops).children("img").prop('src', dragTarget.src); 
    interval = setInterval(showDrop, 1);
    $(ObjectsToHide[indexDrops]).css('visibility', 'visible');    

    contor++;

    if(contor == 7){
        resetBtn.disabled = false;
        $(dragObjects).draggable("disable");
        updateBubble(2);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/cukov/1/edit)

You really need to read [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/)... so many wrong things in your code...

1 - Don't select groups with ID:

```
ObjectsToHide.push(document.getElementById("toChange" + i));
```

instead use a class to select multiple elements.

```
ObjectsToHide = $('.class');
```

2 - Don't save an index:

```
indexDrags = dragObjects.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
```

instead save the element itself in the var so you dont have to select it again.

```
dragsEl = event.currentTarget;
```

3 - Don't do repetitive queries:

```
$("#dropspot" + indexDrops).css("opacity", 0);
$("#dropspot" + indexDrops).children("img").prop('src', dragTarget.src);
```

instead save the query in a var then reuse it or just chain it.

```
var q = $("#dropspot" + indexDrops)
.css("opacity", 0).children("img")
.prop('src', dragTarget.src);
```

4 - If you just need a single operation timer, use setTimeout. Don't use setInterval unless you want an operation to be repeatedly executed.

5 - You need to reference your libraries when you create a Fiddle. In your case: jquery and jqueryUI.

- read more http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#external-resources

6 - You need absolute reference to your images, or they won't be loaded:

```
src="images/clouds.svg"
```

instead

```
src="http://your.site/images/clouds.svg"
```

Comment: U're right,im begginer :( but still the problem i face with wasnt resolved ... I need contor to increment single time per dropspot even if the dropspot its still active and i drop another element

Comment: Yes,is working but it increase even if i drag again elements in same dropspot ... check ur jsbin with an alert for contor and try to drag elements in first dropspot many times,it is increased :( i need to increase only once for every dropspot

Comment: Damn,1 more thing @rafaelcastrocouto ,how to clear data after reset to count again? i set contor = 0; but it doesnt increment again

Comment: Added lots of comments so you understand what is going on in the code ... http://jsbin.com/cukov/6/edit